# How can I describe running a solution four times through a chromatography unit (in an instruction)?

Tags: terminology, biotechnology, chromatography

I'm translating a document from Russian:

> The mean retention time for the first four injections of RNase should be (40.8± 2) min. If the mean RT is beyond this range, adjust the gradient system (change the content of acetonitrile within the 20% - 32% range) and **chromatograph** the RNase solution four times.

I'm aware that we don't use **chromatograph** as a verb in English usually, but we do use it in Russian this way. What would be the generic English expression for this, usable in a procedure description? I know that we have the word **run** but this might be too colloquial for an official paper.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about language and not biology.

Comment: @terdon -  it's about **terminology** used in biotech, as pointed out by one of the tags. Had I asked it on ELL SE, it would have been voted for closure as off-topic too, or the replies would have been not very professional.

Comment: I feel it is more about the use of a specific word and not jargon. I just don't think this sort of question is on topic here since it isn't really about biology but about English. By the way, have a look at yesterday's chat transcript, we did find a few examples of its being used as a verb. Personally, I would say *and run the RNAse solution through the chromatographer four times*, but this isn't really my field.

Comment: @terdon - I see. I decided to bring it out from the chat area to help out (possibly) some fellow translators, web surfers etc.

Comment: Sure, and only one user so far feels it is off topic. I need to get another 3 to agree with me, and perhaps I'm alone in my opinion. Also, argh, typo in my previous comment. I meant *. . .  run through the chromatograph*, not *chromatographer*.

Comment: "Pass", "transit", "process"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say simply:

> repeat the chromatography four times

or less formal, but quite acceptable:

> re-run the column (or whatever it is) four times

This puts the emphasis on the process.

But I’m not exactly sure what’s happening. You have four injections of RNAase. If they are not right are you repeating each once or what? If the former, then it would be:

> repeat the chromatography (or re-run the column) for each sample

Comment: It sounds to me as written that the intention is to attain accuracy via averaging a set of four runs, and if target value not attained, make adjustment and repeat another set of four runs until mean is within desired range. Perhaps state as "... then repeat another set of four runs.  Repeat as needed until the desired mean retention time is achieved."

Comment: @N2ition — Could be. But your use of "runs" suggests that is the most natural term to employ.

Answer (score 3):

I would continue to use `inject` to describe loading samples into the liquid chromatography system and replace

> chromatograph the RNAase solution four times.

with

> inject the RNAase solution another four times.

Comment: Thank you! Will **inject** always imply **..and record the chromatogram** in this context?

Comment: I think one can do better than this. The emphasis shouldn't be on injection but on repeating the process of chromatography.